# Class constructor model cannot be invoked without 'new' usando Sequelize

Tags: javascript, nodejs, orm, model, sequelize

Estoy desarrollando una API con `Node.js` utilizando `sequelize` para crear modelos de las tablas de las bases de datos. Utilicé `sequelize-auto` para crear de manera automática los modelos pero a la hora de implementarlos me lanza un error que ni siquiera es sobre el modelo que estoy queriendo implementar. Busqué pero no pude encontrar la solución. Cualquier ayuda es agradecida y bienvenida

El init-models.js que generó `sequelize-auto`:

```
var DataTypes = require("sequelize").DataTypes;
var __cuentas_corrientes_clientes = require("./_cuentas_corrientes_clientes");
var __cuerpo_pedido = require("./_cuerpo_pedido");
var __pedidos = require("./_pedidos");
var _articulos = require("./articulos");
var _auth_user = require("./auth_user");
var _categorias = require("./categorias");
var _clientes = require("./clientes");
var _cuentas_corrientes_clientes = require("./cuentas_corrientes_clientes");
var _cuerpo_pedido = require("./cuerpo_pedido");
var _fotos_articulos = require("./fotos_articulos");
var _localidades = require("./localidades");
var _parametros_tipos_articulos = require("./parametros_tipos_articulos");
var _pedidos = require("./pedidos");
var _profile = require("./profile");
var _provincias = require("./provincias");
var _rubros = require("./rubros");
var _tipodocu = require("./tipodocu");
var _tipos_contribuyentes = require("./tipos_contribuyentes");
var _tipos_documentos = require("./tipos_documentos");
var _usuarios = require("./usuarios");
var _zonas = require("./zonas");

function initModels(sequelize) {
  var _cuentas_corrientes_clientes = __cuentas_corrientes_clientes(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var _cuerpo_pedido = __cuerpo_pedido(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var _pedidos = __pedidos(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var articulos = _articulos(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var auth_user = _auth_user(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var categorias = _categorias(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var clientes = _clientes(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var cuentas_corrientes_clientes = _cuentas_corrientes_clientes(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var cuerpo_pedido = _cuerpo_pedido(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var fotos_articulos = _fotos_articulos(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var localidades = _localidades(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var parametros_tipos_articulos = _parametros_tipos_articulos(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var pedidos = _pedidos(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var profile = _profile(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var provincias = _provincias(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var rubros = _rubros(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var tipodocu = _tipodocu(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var tipos_contribuyentes = _tipos_contribuyentes(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var tipos_documentos = _tipos_documentos(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var usuarios = _usuarios(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var zonas = _zonas(sequelize, DataTypes);

  return {
    _cuentas_corrientes_clientes,
    _cuerpo_pedido,
    _pedidos,
    articulos,
    auth_user,
    categorias,
    clientes,
    cuentas_corrientes_clientes,
    cuerpo_pedido,
    fotos_articulos,
    localidades,
    parametros_tipos_articulos,
    pedidos,
    profile,
    provincias,
    rubros,
    tipodocu,
    tipos_contribuyentes,
    tipos_documentos,
    usuarios,
    zonas,
  };
}
module.exports = initModels;
module.exports.initModels = initModels;
module.exports.default = initModels;
```

Uno de los modelos que cita el error _cuentas_corrientes_clientes.js:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('_cuentas_corrientes_clientes', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    id_empresa: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    id_cliente: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    fecha: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: true
    },
    comprobante: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(2),
      allowNull: true
    },
    tipo: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(1),
      allowNull: true
    },
    sucursal: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    numero: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    fecha_vencimiento: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: true
    },
    debe: {
      type: DataTypes.DOUBLE(14,2),
      allowNull: false
    },
    haber: {
      type: DataTypes.DOUBLE(14,2),
      allowNull: false
    },
    saldo: {
      type: DataTypes.DOUBLE(14,2),
      allowNull: false
    },
    concepto: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: true
    },
    saldo_comprobante: {
      type: DataTypes.DOUBLE(14,2),
      allowNull: false
    },
    condicion: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
      allowNull: true
    },
    id_comprobante: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    id_pago: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    usuario_q: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(8),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: '_cuentas_corrientes_clientes',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

Traceback del error:

```
D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\Node.js\models\init-models.js:32
  var cuentas_corrientes_clientes = _cuentas_corrientes_clientes(sequelize, DataTypes)
                                    ^

TypeError: Class constructor model cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at initModels (D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\Node.js\models\init-models.js:32:37)
8)                                                    r:999:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Luca Elbio\Proyectos\Nod8)e.js\routes\index.js:5:21)                            e.js\routes\index.js:5:21)      
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)er:1095:14)                                           e starting...
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que el código autogenerado te ha creado clases, pero estás intentando usar esas clases como funciones. Te muestro como reproducir el error:

```js
class Modelo {
  constructor() {
    this.propiedad="texto";
  }
}
let m = new Modelo();
comsole.log(m.propiedad)
Modelo() //llamo al constructor sin new
```

Así que supongo que la solución es simplemente poner la palabra reservada delante:

```
let cuentas_corrientes_clientes = new _cuentas_corrientes_clientes(sequelize, DataTypes);
```

Comment: Hola Pablo! Disculpa las molestias pero porqué me lo pide en algunos modelos y en otros no? Por cierto, muchas gracias! Tu solución funcionó a la perfección!

Comment: No sé cómo trabaja sequelize-auto, habría que ver las características de los modelos y qué ha generado exactamente